# New Xamarin.Forms project from existing solution overwrites previously deployed app C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.forms, clone

I have a Xamarin Forms solution with iOS and android projects. I deployed it on Android.

Now, I created new solution and copied previous solutions' projects into the new solution.

Basically I need new instance of an app that has the same code like previous one with different Name only.

However when I deploy new Solutions' android project it overwrites the original one.

How can I clone projects in a way they are not treated as the same project?

Comment: You need to change the package name and namespace for solution.

Comment: Ok, so I change the moved project's name and namespace. After changing name the nuget dependencies show yellow exclamation marks

Answer (score 0):

Change the application's package name in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

For iOS, change the Bundle Identifier in `info.plist`